# Vector reflection and rotations

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that reflecting $R_2$ across the line $y = x$ and then reflecting it across the $y$−axis is the same as rotating it counterclockwise by $90$ degrees.

I know how to prove this statement geometrically, but I'm assuming the question is asking me to prove this through rotational vectors, which I'm not sure how to prove.

Comment: Do you know what a [rotation matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Put $\alpha=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and $\beta=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$  in
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos2\beta& sin2\beta\\
sin2\beta& -\cos2\beta
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\cos2\alpha& sin2\alpha\\
sin2\alpha& -\cos2\alpha
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1\\
1& 0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0& -1\\
1& 0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2}& -sin\dfrac{\pi}{2}\\
sin\dfrac{\pi}{2}& \cos\dfrac{\pi}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

In general $Re_{l(\beta)}Re_{l(\alpha)}=Ro_{2(\beta-\alpha)}$